# Firebase Auth: Invite User to Company

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Here's my question. To access our web app, the users must be invited.

Each user belongs to a Company. The first person in that company is the admin, who can invite other users. They'll get an email link to sign up.

Now the next phase, how do we add the newly signed up user to the existing company? My initial hunch would be to use Dynamic Links, but I'm a little lost.

Comment: you mean how to sign up users or how to send the invitation link?

Comment: I mean how to ensure the invited user is attached to the existing company. Ideally they'd get a link to sign up (with or without service providers like Google), and immediately be attached to said company upon sign up.